# How to capture the change of a data attribute on an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to capture the change of 'data-value' on a button element?

// dropdown box

```
<button data-value="">'click'</button>
<ul>
 <li>option1</li>
 <li>option2</li>
</ul>
```

I need 1), 2), 3)

```
1) click li
2) data-value="" -> data-value="1"
3) $(button).on('change?', function() {} );
```

but change event support ONLY input, text tag not data-value
and click event doesn't work. no change data-value right after 'click' event .

so HOW do i get the change event of 'data-value' ?

Answer (score 2):

To detect changes to element attributes, you can use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button");

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationList) => {
  mutationList.forEach(({ attributeName, oldValue, target, type }) => {
    if (type === "attributes" && attributeName === "data-value") {
      console.log(
        `${attributeName} changed from '${oldValue}' to '${target.dataset.value}'`
      );
    }
  });
});
observer.observe(btn, { attributes: true, attributeOldValue: true });

// Delegated event listener at <ul>
document.querySelector("ul").addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {
  const li = target.closest("li");
  if (li) {
    const option = li.dataset.option;
    if (option !== undefined) {
      btn.dataset.value = option;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
li { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<button data-value="">'click'</button>
<ul>
 <li data-option="1">option1</li>
 <li data-option="2">option2</li>
</ul>
```